# Android Does my app have a memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-studio

I was looking at the memory usage in android studio and noticed that every time I launch my app, the memory increases by a few MB. I've never got a OutOfMemory exception crash report from any of my supported devices. I'm not familiar with a lot of the tools included in the android sdk so I'm not sure if this signifies a memory leak or not.

In the android studio memory monitor, this is what the graph looks like after 3 launches: 
[image: memory monitor]

As you can see, the memory increases a few MB each launch.

Does this mean I have a memory leak?
If so what steps can I take to find the source of the memory leaks?

Comment: Anyone? I know the question is vague but the android documentation seems to only have articles debugging ram usage on dalvik VM, i'm targeting lollipop (which is 60%+ of my users). Anymore info needed please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure your app doesn't have memory leaks you need to do two things:

1. Make a heap dump.
2. Analyze it with some memory analyzer.

The way to obtain a heap dump is described in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#HeapDump).
Once you have your dump, you can load it into the memory analyzer tool (I prefer `YourKit`, but you can pick up any analyzer you like) and look for leaked objects (the steps to do it can be found in the documentation of chosen memory analyzer).

Simple `YourKit` workflow: start the analyzer, open the heap dump via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. You'll see the screen similar to attached below:

[image]

Click the `Inspections` button on the left side and then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or `Run All` button). The inspection you're interested in is `Objects retained by inner class back references` contained within `Possible leaks` group. Here I have only `String` objects, which can be considered normal. Any time you see here some of your own classes, you have a memory leak. You can click on your objects (if you have them listed here) to see which references it has and who references it to understand what's the leak source.

Comment: thanks for the info, i did 2 heap dumps, the second one I launched my app again, and in YourKit it seems that all my object counts increase, literally all of them, Strings, TextViews, RelativeLayouts. Is this normal? or does it signify a memory leak?

Comment: @jefferson seems like that. I've edited my answer to show how you can find the source of the memory leak.

Comment: Thanks so much for that. i'm still a little confused with finding the leaked references in those objects. Here is a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/5NH7SSt.png?1 , I see one of my fragments there, but the size is small only a few bytes. I also see that dexCache is quite large but I'm not sure how to interpret that?